# Fix a Frame of an object in Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, wireframe

I want to frame an object in Blender Game Engine. 
The idea is that I need this frame adjust correctly to the object regardless of its size or rotation. Also, if the object is near or further (so the dimensions of the object changes) the frame should be changing accordingly.

Comment: Is the frame an overlay or could you just put a box-like shape around your object?